# Why am I unable to sort list by difference of 2 fields?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor, helper

So I have a list of items.

Each item has a like or dislike button. I wish to sort it by total score, which is = # likes less # dislikes.

I am trying to understand why:

1. The below handlebar + sort is not working on client side and how to make it work?
2. If a server side solution would be better and why? (server side takes up unnecessary disk space from what I have learnt in other posts and premature optimization - Yes, Im still in the early stages)

This is how I store it in the **list in items.js within collections** (ground 0 form).

```
var item = _.extend(itemAttributes, {
  lovers:       [], 
  likes:        0,
  haters:       [], 
  dislikes:     0
  //popularity:      likes - dislikes I tried inserting in collection but doesnt work too 
});
```

So Im sorting it via a handlebar helper + extension of the main list controller

**This is the handlebar segment**

```
Template.registerHelper('popularity', function(likes, dislikes) {
    var popularity = likes - dislikes;
    return popularity;
```

**This is the sorter in router.js**

```
BestItemController = ItemListController.extend({
  sort: {popularity: -1},
    nextPath: function() {
    return Router.routes.BestItem.path({itemsLimit: this.itemsLimit() + this.increment})
  }
});
```

So the handlebar `popularity` calculations actually does work, the popularity score appears on addition of `{{ popularity 123numbersxx }}`

However the sorting doesnt work, probably because the sorting does not sort "on the surface" calculations, but rather on the actual item and its fields?

I tried to insert an additional schema field (see above commented line). However that causes errors which states `likes` are not defined.

Would anyone help guide me a little on this? 
Also if you think my method of doing things is bad, appreciate any other ways? For example if sorting on the individual template helper.js files rather than on the main router.js files.

Many thanks!

Comment: Cannot be done without `.aggregate()`, therefore server side. Plently of answers about this. Your most solid option is to "store" the calculated value of `"likes"  - "dislikes"` in another field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB get all fields + sort by value computed from multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585135/mongodb-get-all-fields-sort-by-value-computed-from-multiple-fields)

Comment: By the way, @Blakes Seven, you can achieve that server side using two other ways than `.aggregate`. The first one is using `cursor.Observe()`, see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161. The second one is using collection hooks, you update the sorted list before each insert.

Comment: Thanks folks, have updated my question to make it more robust and different from what @BlakesSeven posted as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that client-side. Here is how I would proceed:

You probably display your `item` to be sorted using an `{{#each item}}` iteration. I would replace `item` in the `#each` by a custom helper and create a function, using a cursor or an array as an argument, that will sort your items using the current sorting settings.

Your helper could look like that:

```
Template.items.helpers({
  sortedItems: function(){
    return sortMyItems(items.find()) //add .fetch() if you need an array,
                                     //or directly your array if you already have it in a variable.
  }
});
```

And at the beginning of your file, you add the `sortMyItems` function where you return the sorted list of items.

```
sortMyItems = function(cursor) {
    if(!cursor) {
        return [];
    }
    var sortBy = Session.get("sortBy");// in your case, it would be set to "popularity"
    var sortAscending = Session.get("sortAscending ");
    if(typeof(sortAscending) == "undefined") sortAscending = true;
    var sorted = [];
    var raw = cursor.fetch();
    // sort
    if(sortBy) {
        sorted= _.sortBy(raw, sortBy);

        // descending?
        if(!sortAscending) {
            sorted= sorted.reverse();
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

here I use Session vars, but I advise you to rather use reactive variables or reactive dictionary, since this is a feature related to the current view only.

Comment: Thanks, now allow me some time to digest it and try implementing it now :)